# Android fragments overlap after afew rotating screen

Tags: android, android-fragments

I read some questions like it, but I dont understand well  what should I do in my hiearchy?

I have

```
<fragment
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        class="com.****.****.ui.TabsFragment" />
```

for tab menu on bottom of screen

and

```
<FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/details"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/tickerLL"
        android:layout_below="@id/header"
        android:background="@drawable/background" />
```

for other will created fragments.

I have 9 tab menus, everyone is a fragment.

Some fragments's landscape are another activity. And I rotate back phone, fragments are working well. But if I rotate fast after and after, My fragment Activty, TabsFragment and and other created fragments are recreated and my fragments are overlapping.

I manage my fragments in TabsFragment. And they works dynamicly, my abstract fragment class, has a previous fragment and subfragment. When I press back,  previous fragment closes its subfragment and null it.

What should I do?

Answer (score 2):

During a configuration change, Android restores or recreates all fragments that the old activity had when setting up the new activity. Hence, you need to take that into account when working with the new activity instance -- do not assume that you are starting with a clean slate.

Comment: @CommonsWare : Do you know how to begin from Clean State as you said when using Fragments?

Comment: @AlexTran: I suppose that you can run some `FragmentTransaction` to clear out all the old ones, if they were added via transactions of their own.